# How to combine two data frames using dplyr or other packages?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(index=c(0,3,4),n1=c(1,2,3))  
df1
#  index n1
# 1    0  1
# 2    3  2
# 3    4  3

df2 = data.frame(index=c(1,2,3),n2=c(4,5,6))  
df2
#   index n2
# 1     1  4
# 2     2  5
# 3     3  6
```

I want to join these to:

```
  index n
1     0 1
2     1 4
3     2 5
4     3 8  (index 3 in two df, so add 2 and 6 in each df)
5     4 3
6     5 0  (index 5 not exists in either df, so set 0)
7     6 0  (index 6 not exists in either df, so set 0)
```

The given data frames are just part of large dataset. Can I do it using `dplyr` or other packages in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` (would be efficient for bigger datasets).  I am not changing the column names, as the `rbindlist` uses the name of the first dataset ie. in this case `n` from the second column (Don't know if it is a feature or bug).  Once you join the datasets by `rbindlist`, group it by column `index` i.e. (`by=index`) and do the sum of `n` column (`list(n=sum(n))` )

```
 library(data.table)
 rbindlist(list(data.frame(index=0:6,n=0), df1,df2))[,list(n=sum(n)), by=index]
     index n
 #1:     0 1
 #2:     1 4
 #3:     2 5
 #4:     3 8
 #5:     4 3
 #6:     5 0
 #7:     6 0
```

Or using `dplyr`.  Here, the `column names` of all the datasets should be the same. So, I am changing it before `binding` the datasets using `rbind_list`.  If the `names` are different, there will be multiple columns for each `name`.  After joining the datasets, group it by `index` and then use `summarize` and do the `sum` of column `n`.

```
 library(dplyr)
 nm1 <- c("index", "n") 
 colnames(df1) <- colnames(df2) <- nm1 
 rbind_list(df1,df2, data.frame(index=0:6, n=0)) %>% 
                                          group_by(index) %>%
                                          summarise(n=sum(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could do with the base functions `aggregate` and `rbind`

```
df1 = data.frame(index=c(0,3,4),n=c(1,2,3))  
df2 = data.frame(index=c(1,2,3),n=c(4,5,6))  
aggregate(n~index, rbind(df1, df2, data.frame(index=0:6, n=0)), sum)
```

which returns

```
  index n
1     0 1
2     1 4
3     2 5
4     3 8
5     4 3
6     5 0
7     6 0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
names(df1) <- c("index", "n")                # set colnames of df1 to target
df3 <- rbind(df1,setNames(df2, names(df1)))  # set colnnames of df2 and join
df <- df3 %>% dplyr::arrange(index)          # sort by index
```

Cheers.