# Combine 2 dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-science

I am doing this in R
I have 2 dataframes A & B.
A has 9 columns, while B has 8 columns which are in common.
A consist of unique ID 1-500, while B consist of unique ID 501-1100.

I need to combine both the tables.

Please help me with the command.
It would be great if multiple possible commands are told.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be very helpful if you can provide an example of your data. Please look into `dput` or providing a reprex: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Edit: You're probably looking for `join` or `merge`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to add a vector as a column with missing values to B and then just bind both datframes by rows:

```
empty<-c(NA * nrow(B))
cbind(B, empty)

rbind(A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in multiple ways using base functions and other packages:

You could try [merge](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/rw1001/library/base/html/merge.html):

```
merge(x, y, by, by.x, by.y, sort = TRUE)
```

Dplyr:

- Dplyr [join](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html)
- Dplyr [bind](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html)

And data.table. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520644/how-to-combine-two-data-frames-using-dplyr-or-other-packages).